# import("somePath") as return value

Tags: typescript

I am working with p5.js and Typescript.

p5 has an function called `line` it is used to draw a line using the coordinates x1, y1, x2 and y2

VS code tells me the signature of this function is `line(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number): import("D:/Users/Myname/source/repos/2D-Game/node_modules/@types/p5/index.d.ts")`

which is ok for me but when I try to write a function like this

```js
function myLine(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number): import("D:/Users/Myname/source/repos/2D-Game/node_modules/@types/p5/index.d.ts") {

}
```

typescript tells me `An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing 'D:/Users/Samuel/source/repos/2D-Game/node_modules/@types/p5/index' instead.ts(2691)`

so why is p5 allowed to use import like this and I am not?

Comment: As the error suggests, declaration files shouldn't be imported directly. The declarations should generally be available either globablly or applied to some modules, namespace, etc. VSCode is doing its best to show you what the definitions are or where they come from. Are you sure that you don't want to provide a type that you've already imported, like `line` or maybe `ReturnType<line>`?

Comment: Ok so the right way would be to show `line(x1: number, y1: number, x2: number, y2: number): p5` but vs code is not able to resolve the import so it just showes me the import?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `typeof import(..)`.  Also, you should not use the full path in the `import` and instead import it via the npm package name then the rest of the path.  e.g. `./node_modules/@types/p5/index` => `p5/index`. Here's a minimal demo that showcases what you need to do:

```
declare module "p5.d.ts" {
    export let setup: () => void;
    export let draw: () => void;
    // ..
}

declare function loadP5(): typeof import("p5.d.ts");

const asdf = loadP5();

asdf.draw = () => {
    console.log("DRAW");
};
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiADgVgDpgCAXAZy3gG8Aoee+EADx2RhPkw7JBLRwBc8ABQBKeAF4AfPABuyAJbAA3HQbNW7Tr3jAYUAO5CxkmfKWqG8APTX4BAjQC+NGqEiwEAMzQA7MCQKyL6cyFDAAAp4YkIkAJ44IMhe8AqImiTCuITE5FiiqjRgwWQcUGTAKRKh4VFiheWVRPoGkiLi0tRq9MW+ZMiYBBDIAOZZACIASgCCAOr5qk7KQA)